# Understanding the Dispatcher in C#

Tags: c#

I'm watching a video on asynchronous C# 5, and in the example he has an asynchronous method and a lambda callback function. Because the lambda callback function executes on a separate thread, trying to alter the UI within it causes an exception.

To mitigate this, he uses `Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)`

However I am confused about this. I made a new .NET 4.5 project and tried to find the Dispatcher class, but I can't find it anywhere. Google told me it was in the System.Windows.Threading namespace but I don't have this dll on my computer, only System.Windows

I also don't quite get how it works - looking at the MSDN documentation I can't really see how the Dispatcher (which presumably deals with all threads) will do stuff on the UI thread - the RunAsync method doesn't specify the thread that operations execute on.

I considered that maybe the dispatcher just runs things on the thread that was used to create the dispatcher, but since I can't try this out locally due to the above issue, I am at a loss.

Can anyone direct me to the solution?

Comment: Don't confuse namespaces with assemblies. Types in a namespace can be spread across multiple assemblies and the namespace name doesn't have to be the same as the assembly name. So there is no `System.Windows.Threading` assembly even though there is a namespace with that name.

Comment: Maybe this is Windows 8 Dispatcher via CoreDispatcher?

Comment: I think he uses the [RunAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) method of the CoreDispatcher and that is part of the new Windows API and is in namespace Windows.UI.Core

Comment: The Dispatcher lives in the WindowsBase.DLL.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx

Comment: can you post a link to the video?

Comment: Video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-011 and I've found it in Windowsbase.DLL thanks for that. It's called Dispatcher. However it has no `RunAsync` method. It's about the 20 minute mark in the video that he uses the Dispatcher.

Comment: @SLC - what is your UI framework, which version?  There is no Dispatcher in WinForms.

Comment: I've just made a new blank .net 4.5 project and I am poking about.

Comment: @SLC - Dispatcher only exists in WPF projects.  So if you have a WinForm project open you won't be able to use the Dispatcher there is a similar class for doing this same thing in WinForm projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-011) you have mentioned is about developing Windows Store app with the Windows Runtime and .NET Framework 4.5 and he uses the [RunAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208211.aspx) method of the CoreDispatcher and that is part of the new Windows API and is in namespace Windows.UI.Core.

Stop as 00:20:21 and take a look at IntelliSense